# create a cache when reading a slow IO device

Tags: c++, linux, file, caching, memory

I need to read a few pieces each time from a file located in a slow device, so I want to read the whole file one time, is there a way to do that. keep in mind I don't want to read it to a CPU memory buffer since I need to call another API that needs a file path as a parameter, inside the API it handles the read/seek on the file, so seems I cannot pass a memory address to the API directly.

Comment: Copy the file to a memory-backed filesystem first?

Comment: Yeah, do you think copy the file under the /tmp/xxx is the good idea, is the file under /tmp with some cache so it will be faster than other locations such as /home/xxx?

Comment: That is impossible to answer without seeing your computer configuration. Mount points with type tmpfs are memory-backed, so that is as fast as you can reasonably get.

Answer (score 0):

If speed is what you're aiming for then I would go with [`mmap(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) which can also be shared across contexts.

Comment: If I use mmap, then how can I pass the path to the API which receive the file path as a param?

Comment: @BiaoCao: Same way as you do now. The trick is that `mmap` strongly suggests the OS to keep the file content mapped into memory. Since the OS has the file content in memory anyway, the other process will get those contents quickly once it asks the OS for the same file content.